# Webscraping code to import logs from a website which is about to die

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

We all know that the famous twitch log site OverRustleLogs is getting shut down. So I decided to do some web scraping to download my favourite streamer's logs using BeautifulSoup. How can make this code run more efficient?

```
import requests
import os
import shutil
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://overrustlelogs.net/'
page = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser').findAll('div', {'class': 'list-group'})
names_3 =  [i.text.replace('\n ', '/').replace('\n', '') for i in soup[0].findAll('a',{'class':'list-group-item list-group-item-action'})]

for name in names_3:
    url_n = 'https://overrustlelogs.net'+str(name)
    page = requests.get(url_n)
    soup_n = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser').findAll('div', {'class': 'list-group'})
    names_3_n =  [i.text.replace('\n ', '/').replace('\n', '') for i in soup_n[0].findAll('a', {'class':'list-group-item list-group-item-action'})]

for file in names_3_n:
    try:
            os.makedirs(f'./files{name}{file}')
    except:
        if FileExistsError:
            shutil.rmtree(f'./files{name}{file}')
            os.makedirs(f'./files{name}{file}')

    url_n1 = 'https://overrustlelogs.net'+str(name)+str(file)
    print(url_n1)
    page = requests.get(url_n1)
    soup_n1 = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser').findAll('div', {'class': 'list-group'})
    names_3_n1 =  [i.text.replace('\n ', '/').replace('\n', '') for i in soup_n1[0].findAll('a', {'class':'list-group-item list-group-item-action'})]

    for filename in names_3_n1:
        f = open(f'./files{name}{file}{filename}', 'wb')
        r = requests.get(url_n1+str(filename))
        f.write(r.content)
```